# Invalid initializer in C when creating an array via a function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, initialization

I want to create an array of type set and have all the nodes set to NULL, hence I used calloc. However, I'm getting an invalid initializer in that one line in main function. Why's that?

```
struct set {
    int capacity;
    int size;
    char *array;
};


struct set *create_graph(int nodes)
{
  struct set *graph = calloc(nodes - 1, sizeof(struct set));

  return graph;
}
int main()
{

  struct set* graph[] = create_graph(4);
}
```

Comment: Just lose the `[]`. You will still have a pointer to the same block of memory, and individual structs within that can still be accessed using the `[i]` indexing system.

Comment: why `nodes - 1`?

Comment: You cannot have an array with elements of type `struct set` with "all the nodes set to `NULL`", because `NULL` is not a valid value of type `struct set`.  What you are getting from `calloc` is an array with all bits zero.  That may be exactly what you want, but it is not at all the same thing as what you said.

Comment: @JohnBollinger should I just use malloc instead? My goal is to add variables of type set in graph[] so I assumed that I can initialize them all with NULL and then start adding the set variables

Comment: @yano I dunno, tis specified in our assignment :/

Comment: @JonathanF, my point is not about which allocation function to use.  Either `malloc` or `calloc` can allocate the memory you need.  `calloc` will additionally initialize the allocated memory (to all-bits-zero) whereas `malloc` will leave it uninitialized.  My observation is that in no way and by no means can you get objects of type `struct set` with `NULL` values.  This is relevant because the question suggests that you may have a confusion between `struct set` and `struct set *`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger now that you mention it, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @JonathanF, a `struct set` is a compound object comprising two `int`s and a `char *`.  Storage for one such object will be at least twice the size of an `int` plus the size of a `char *`.  A `struct set *` is a scalar object whose value, when valid and non-null, is the *address* of a `struct set`.  Note well that declaring or allocating a `struct set *` *does not* automatically give you a `struct set` for it to point to -- that's what something like your `calloc()` accomplishes, for example.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
 struct set* graph[] = create_graph(4);
```

declares an array of pointers. You just need

```
 struct set* graph = create_graph(4);
```

Comment: Ooh, cuz create_graph already returns an array with nodes of NULL?

Comment: @JonathanF No, because you allocate an array of `struct set`.

Comment: @AdrianMole I would always bracket so if you are saying I have the precedence wrong that I accept that.

Comment: @AdrianMole so, is `graph = ` correct or should I keep the brackets?

Comment: @JonathanF You don't need the square brackets in the initial assignment but you can use them to access individual elements in the allocated memory block.

Comment: @JonathanF my answer was correct, just the explanation of why what you did didnt work, that was wrong